# Java imported package does not exist

Tags: java, import, compiler-errors, classpath

I am trying to use pdfbox to write a simple pdf file but the problem is that I am getting error :

```
cannot find symbol class PDDocument
```

I have downloaded the jar files into the same folder the program exists.  How to fix this compilation error?

```
package org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

import java.io.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

public class pdf
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
}
}
```

Comment: Is this compilation error from javac run on a command line, or from your IDE?  It's not enough to put the jar in the same directory - you need to add it to the classpath of the tool you're using.

Comment: `package org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;`  Your package should not be the fully qualified name of an existing class!

Comment: thanks andrew. i will remove it now.

Answer (score 12):

Putting the jar in the same folder or package does not add it to the class path. You need to mention the path of the jar in your class path while running your java program. Here is the syntax for that:

To compile:

```
javac -classpath .;yourjar.jar src/your/package/*.java
```

To run

```
java -classpath .;yourjar.jar src/your/package/yourprogrammeclassname
```

Comment: For compilation you can set CLASSPATH environment variable.

Comment: Any classes your code uses that you didn't write yourself need their locations pointed out to the compiler so that it can link them into your code when it compiles everything together. The filesystem paths to those classes are called classpaths. There are two ways to tell your compiler where to look for external classes. One is to pass the "-classpath" flag when you call the compiler and follow it with a semicolon-delimited list of paths where the classes are found.

Comment: I have just installed eclipse.  I have installed eclipse and added the jar file but i am getting this error:


The declared package "org.apache.pdfbox.examples.pdmodel" does not match the expected package "" pdf.java /Test/src line 1 Java Problem

This is my import statements and packages
"package org.apache.pdfbox.examples.pdmodel;

import java.io.*;

import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;

Is there something wrong?

Comment: Thanks all for spending so much on this..Couldn't have done without all of you. It is the classpath. I wish to close the question with solved.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make sure that the JAR file is on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.To ensure, i use good example, i use CreateBlankPDF.java from the apache's website. To compile, i did this, javac -cp pdfbox-1.8.1.jar CreateBlankPDF.java and to run the program, i did this:java -classpath pdfbox-1.8.1.jar CreateBlankPDF
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CreateBlankPDF
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CreateBlankPDF

Answer (score 2):

having a similar issue I found that I did not have the correct syntax on the import line in the java source

doing a compile as the following (on windows):

```
javac -cp .;commons-io-2.4.jar AgeFileFilterTest.java
```

with commons-io-2.4.jar in the same folder as AgeFileFilterTest.java

I was getting error:

```
import org.apache.*;
^
AgeFileFilterTest.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
            displayFiles(directory, new AgeFileFilter(cutoffDate));
                                        ^
```

It was puzzling becuase it seemed all was in place; the jar was in the folder, defined in the classpath, and upon jar content inspection I could see what was being referenced-  using 7zip I opened the jar file and could see:

```
commons-io-2.4.jar\org\apache\commons\io\filefilter\AbstractFileFilter.class
```

I then read in some post **"you do not import the class"** which got me to think about the import syntax...

I changed it from:

```
import org.apache.*;
```

changing it to:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.*;
```

and wala compile error gone using: 
  javac -cp .;commons-io-2.4.jar AgeFileFilterTest.java

and program worked using

```
java -cp .;commons-io-2.4.jar AgeFileFilterTest
```